# Error "bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me gustaría saber como solucionar un error que me da en este trozo de código:

```
Self.errMsgs ={ 
1: b"No hay tal usuario",
2: b"Acceso denegado",
3: b"Disco lleno"


}
```

El mensaje de error que me pone es :

> bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.

Lo que quiero es que pueda coger un mensaje de esos dependiendo de ese código que hay delante de él.  Por ejemplo, mensaje : Disco lleno[3]
Solo se mostraría el mensaje.

Es que no se como ponerlo de otra forma. Necesito que los códigos sean bytes, para poder enviarlos mediante struct.

Comment: El error te lo arroja al momento de declarar el diccionario, al momento de enviarlo, mostrarlo?

Answer (score 0):

En Python 3 el tipo `bytes` es simplemente una secuencia de octetos (enteros en el rango 0 - 255).

Los *"literales de bytes"* al ser declarados solo pueden contener caracteres ASCII, los **valores con valor numérico mayor a 128 debe expresarse mediante secuencias de escape al declarar un literal** o generan el error que describes. Esto no ocurre en tu ejemplo, a no ser que tengas más opciones en tu diccionario en las que si se de este caso.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código causaría el mismo error que describes:

```
self.errMsgs = { 
    1: b"Camión",
    2: b"Cigüeña"
    }
```

porque tenemos tres caracteres que no pertenecen a ASCII, como son `ó`, `ü` y `ñ`.

Si necesitas que las claves sean de tipo bytes, puedes conseguirlo de varias formas:

- **Usando secuencias de escape**, de acuerdo por supuesto a la codificación que quieras usar. Para el ejemplo anterior y UTF-8 sería algo así:

  ```
  self.errMsgs ={ 
      1: b"Cami\xc3\xb3n",
      2: b"Cig\xc3\xbce\xc3\xb1a"
      }
  ```
- **Usando el método `str.encode`**:

  ```
  self.errMsgs = { 
      1: "Camión".encode("utf-8"),
      2: "Cigüeña".encode("utf-8")
      }
  ```
- **Usando el constructor `bytes`**:

  ```
  self.errMsgs = { 
      1: bytes("Camión", "utf-8"),
      2: bytes("Cigüeña", "utf-8")
      }
  ```

Si necesitas la cadena UTF-8 de vuelta, decodifica:

```
msg = self.errMsgs[1]
msg.decode("utf-8")
```